# Styling only one VCL component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3, vcl-styles

I know, that it's possible to disable custom styling for components, but how can I enable styles for only one component class? For example leave the whole form and all components on it unskinned, and skin only TButton. Like on this image.

[image]

Comment: if you need just styled button - try to find styled button - `TButton` descendant component wich looks not like usual `TButton`.
Adding VCL Styles functionality to the project and then disabling it for a whole project, excluding `TButton`, is not good way to skin just one button in project.

Comment: It just looks strange to have styling funtionality in Delphi and to not be able to use it without applying to the whole application.

Comment: @Zelenov I don't find it strange - it was designed for that purpose. As long as you're applying a theme, you're assumed to be skinning the entire application. Personally I find it strange to use these styles to skin only certain controls - given the mechanism in how it works. For your purpose, I would create my own custom button control, which is rather trivial.

Answer (score 13):

Most of the VCL controls internally uses the [`StyleServices`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Themes.StyleServices) global function to get the methods to draw the control. So if you are not using the Vcl Styles, the `StyleServices` return an instance to the windows API functions to draw themed controls (UxTheme API's). because that there is not way to skin (apply the Vcl Styles) to only a single class control (at least which you draw the control yourself).

So the only alternative is apply a Vcl Styles and then disable for all the controls except the one type which you are looking for.

You can use something like this

```
procedure DisableVclStyles(Control : TControl;const ClassToIgnore:string);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  if Control=nil then
    Exit;

  if not Control.ClassNameIs(ClassToIgnore) then
   Control.StyleElements:=[];

  if Control is TWinControl then
    for i := 0 to TWinControl(Control).ControlCount-1 do
      DisableVclStyles(TWinControl(Control).Controls[i], ClassToIgnore);
end;
```

Check this form with a Vcl Style

[image]

And now after of call the above method

```
DisableVclStyles(Self,'TButton');
```

[image]

Note : using the *[StyleElements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.StyleElements)* property to enable o disable the vcl styles  doesn't work with some component like (TStringGrid, TBitBtn, TSpeedButton and so on)

Comment: I'm trying this in XE2 and `TControl` doesn't have a property `StyleElements`

Comment: Nevermind I just found another answer of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538890/how-to-color-the-background-of-a-tcombobox-with-vcl-styles-enabled

Comment: what if my component gets created in a DataModule?
when I put " DisableVclStyles(Self,'TButton'); " in the DataModule the IDE returns me this error: Incompatible types: 'TControl' and 'TDMRotinas'