# Form background color with VCL Styles?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I am experimenting with VCL Styles. This might be a silly question, but is it possible to have forms with different backgrounds when using a style? It seems that the form background (client area) is specified in the VCL style designer and it overrides the form's `Color` property.

How can I achieve forms with different background color? For example, I want my modal dialogs have a different background color than the main form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to color the background of a TComboBox with VCL styles enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538890/how-to-color-the-background-of-a-tcombobox-with-vcl-styles-enabled)

Comment: Also useful links are at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906312/

Comment: The link @Arioch'The provided contains the solution, you just need to adapt a few things: ` TFromStyleHookExt= class(TFormStyleHook)` change TWinControlClass(Control). to TForm(Control).  adapt initialization TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TForm_XY, TFromStyleHookExt);  and change WndProc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible : 
if you are using Delphi XE3,XE4,XE5 :
you only need to remove `seClient` from the `StyleElements` property of your form :

```
 Form3.StyleElements := [seFont, seBorder];
```

if you are using delphi xe2: 
you should override the `TFormStyleHook` class ,and catch the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message , and return without processing the default message :

```
type
  TFormStyleHookEx = class(TFormStyleHook)
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TMessage); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  end;
{ TFormStyleHookEx }

procedure TFormStyleHookEx.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

initialization

TStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TForm3, TFormStyleHookEx);
```

[image]

Comment: He is on XE2, StyleElements are not known here.

Comment: nice and concise, but unfortunately IMHO the question is still a duplicate.

Comment: @bummi the answer might be contained in the other thread but since it is specifically about `TForm` I think it does provide value to others.

Comment: @Smasher more convinced than skeptical (70/30) I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Would not retract: the links is a useful one and increases the connectivity. And i cannot remove the voice and then re-insert the link before @bummi's comment