# VCL Styles - Only skin one control

Tags: delphi, vcl, vcl-styles

I only want to skin / style one single control on my form using vcl styles and leave the rest to windows default.

In this example i want to skin the TButton component.

This is my form:

[image]

After applying a VCL style i get:

[image]

But what i want is:

[image]

The Bitmap-Style-Designer included with the IDE didn't seem to allow specifying which controls to skin so maybe there is a "trick" to do this?

Comment: VCL styles isn't designed for this. Use a custom button control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VCL Styles are global to the application. So you can try disabling the VCL Styles for all the controls except for the button how is shown [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031125/styling-only-one-vcl-component-in-delphi) (this method have some limitations), or even better you can **draw the button yourself** using  the VCL Styles look and feel like so.

```
var
  LStyleServices : TCustomStyleServices;
begin
  LStyleServices:=TStyleManager.Style['AnyLoadedVclStyle'];
  //draw the button with using LStyleServices 

  ....       
end;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031125/styling-only-one-vcl-component-in-delphi

Comment: @ChrisB, I just edited the answer.